# My question was edited by a moderator, it was a poor edit, and now edits are locked?

Tags: bug, editing, moderators, aggressive-edits

My question [New employee has offensive Slack handle due to language barrier](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/78511/new-employee-has-offensive-slack-handle-due-to-language-barrier)

Was met with a rather hostile reaction from a moderator, locking the entire question down so that only they could edit it.  And while this moderator was rather rude, I am completely ignoring that and having an issue with the edit made.  The edit says the name is a *translation* but it isn't, if anything it is an abbreviation. Can this be changed?

Comment: Did you read the lock notice?  That's not why the post was locked.  Also, I don't see any rudeness from the *moderator* in the post history.

Comment: @MonicaCellio who's asking about the lock? I'm not.  All I care about is that the edit is inaccurate.

Comment: If you don't care about the lock or the moderator's alleged rudeness, perhaps you shouldn't mention them so prominently in this question.

Comment: I mention them in passing... or does "I am completely ignoring that and having an issue with the edit made." mean nothing?

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't mean much. "I am completely ignoring" this thing that I'm talking about in inflammatory terms. Incidentally, the current version of the question doesn't call it a "translation". Can we assume the issue is now settled? (Never mind, I see you already addressed that last point in your answer.)

Comment: The workplace site suffers from this extremely.  It turns me as well as others off from this place.

Comment: Are you asking for an edit or are you raising a complaint regarding moderation? As it stands this question is really passive aggressively trying to raise a complaint with moderation, by alluding to an offense and complaining about it, then saying we should ignore it.

Comment: If you were *completely ignoring* the moderation you would not mention it. Logical inconsistency. I suggest you edit the remark out of the question and flag all related comments as obsolete. (I don't want to do this, it's *your* post and you may disagree with my edit)

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I see the question was edited again since me posting this question on meta, I am fine with it in its current state.  Why the moderators are so aggressive... who knows.

Comment: This aggression of the moderators would not be acceptable in a PC workplace.  Putting down an OP for providing details that was asked of them is not okay.  If they just corrected them, I'd imagine you'd have had no issue?

Comment: Just a guess, but the mods are aggressive because this is an *very* popular & busy exchange. Hot-topic threads quickly spiral out of control if left unchecked.

Comment: The only aggression I see here is from you.

Comment: when you dox your employee, the love in here is going to be severely curtailed.

Comment: @RichardU I only doxed them because I was asked to.

Comment: @Walle seriously. **never** do that again.  You have no idea how much mischief can be caused by anyone doing a screenshot.  I saw that person's name and I have an eidetic memory.  Not only did you dox him, but you also effectively doxed yourself.  All anyone has to do is look up that name, find out where this person is working, do a little bit of social engineering, and they've got you.  I don't think you understand how serious this is.

Answer (score 11):

I clarified further with an additional edit.

The post was locked for one hour because:

> This post has been locked due to the high amount of off-topic comments generated. For extended discussions, please use chat.

which I did because there were over two dozen comments that continued to be off topic. I encourage you to [read through this documentation in the help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) around comments. Pretty much **all** of this section is relevant, so I won't quote them here.

Also, naming and shaming an employee who is a junior to you? You can't possibly not have expected *those* comments to not get deleted.

Comment: I really could care less about the lock, my issue is the edit is inaccurate. Like, seriously out of left field with the lock issue. Nor do I remotely care that the comments were deleted. Perhaps reading my question instead of bullying is a good use of a moderator's power.

Comment: Where was there shaming? Not that it is that important, just I didn't see it.

Comment: @Kik the problem is the way the OP was doing so was by mocking their colleague and _insisting_ on including their colleague's real name into the post. I'm not really sure how to separate that issue from what you were raising and given that the OP (and others) continued to discuss the real name... :\ if you can edit the question in a way to avoid this, I would _love_ to see an edit ;-)

Comment: @enderland I in no way shape or form was insisting on providing their real name.  I am incredibly offended at that accusation.  I was insisting on providing the **handle being used**. In fact no one mentioned the real name aside from once, just the **handle**.  If you had even the least bit of context to the question, you'd have seen this.

Comment: @Walle you included your coworkers real name in an edit to the post, which was removed by another user (properly). This was also mocked by another vocal proponent on this meta post, in a now deleted comment.

Comment: @enderland yes, that is true.  No one is arguing that -_-

Answer (score 8):

I've just reviewed the revision history and the 64 (!) deleted comments (the vast majority of them not constructive or worse), and I don't see anything "hostile" or "rather rude" from moderators.  Actually, given the attitudes expressed in some of the comments, including *publishing the coworker's real name*, I think enderland showed great restraint.

*Locks* are a standard Stack Exchange feature, used rarely but designed to interrupt something bad that is in progress.  A [comment lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172592/162102) is appropriate when comments have developed a severe case of "not what comments are for".  Locks usually expire in an hour (as in this case) or a day.  The lock notice explains the reason for the lock.

Moderators can edit locked posts.  In this case a moderator edited the post to address an issue that was the source of a lot of the non-constructive comments.  I don't see how that edit could have violated the intentions of an asker who wanted to *solve a problem*, but I can see how it might frustrate people who wanted to gawk at the coworker's expense.

You're apparently upset over one word, "translation", and enderland fixed that, within five minutes of your post, to say "slang" instead.  Next time, consider just asking for the edit you want instead of jumping to accusations of moderator abuse; it'll be much more constructive and productive.

Comment: It's possible to purge sensitive data (like passwords) from a post for mods, I think. Do you think the coworker's real name should be purged that way?

Comment: @muru I've been considering that (got a flag). I don't want to cause harm to the coworker when it feels like he's being made fun of behind his back. On the other hand, I want the community to be able to audit moderators' actions so y'all can see for yourselves what we did or didn't do, since people sometimes make untrue claims. (Granted you can't audit comment deletions, but comments are second-class citizens. Posts are much more important.) I didn't find the post by Googling for the coworker's name, so for now it seems ok to leave things as they are.  When things settle down I might redact.

Comment: We got lucky there, I think. The entry in Google's index seems to be from 13 hours ago, when the post only mentioned the first name and "Pound".

Comment: @Monica Cellio With all due respect, I beg to submit that your priority is incorrect here. Someone's real name being posted on the internet as a subject of ridicule *without permission* is a lot bigger problem than a few frustrated people making allegedly false accusations against a moderator. Request the moderators to purge the person's real name from the history urgently and worry about the false accusations later.

Comment: @MaskedMan that's a good point; I was thinking "not in Google, thus doesn't shame him", but you're right that it being here -- especially with someone agitating against that edit and thus drawing attention to it -- does harm to that person.  It takes two mods to redact, but I'll kick it off and when somebody else gets here we should be able to take care of that.

Comment: @Walle if your goal is constructive and useful discussion, comments like that absolutely are not beneficial.

Comment: If I read revision 4 correctly, the name has been purged (though the first name still appears in other revisions, I suppose that's not too problematic). Thank you, Monica and @enderland!

Comment: @muru Uhm, I still see the coworker's name as well as various variations of the username in the edit history. I am afraid this still has potential to harm the OP (especially since they seem to be in a foreign country/culture). Depending on the employer, the OP *too* could get fired over it if this question becomes "popular"!

Comment: @MaskedMan very true, however, revision 4 was what contained the full name of the coworker in its entirety (first name + surname together) (other entries "just" have the first name and "pound"). I'm not familiar with the redaction process, perhaps the other revisions need to be redacted separately.

Answer (score 2):

Best to be philosophical about these things, it's a fairly minor issue (to the rest of us I think). I can't see anything worth making a fuss over in how it was handled.